# Inner Product in Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $\phi_{1}, \dots, \phi_{n} \in H$ are linearly independent vectors. How can we construct the inner product on $H$ such that $\phi_{1}, \dots, \phi_{n}$ become orthogonal and it still remains a Hilbert space?

Comment: Have you seen the Gramm-Schmidt process?

Comment: I think he wants to keep the $\phi_i$'s, Gram-Schmidt generates new vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V$ be the span of $\phi_1,\dots,\phi_n$, and let $V^\perp$ be its orthogonal complement. Introduce new inner product on $V$ so that $\langle \phi_i,\phi_j  \rangle_V = \delta_{ij}$ (this formula defines it for basis vectors; extend by linearity).

Every vector $u$ in $H$ is the sum of vectors $u_1\in  V$ and $u_2\in V^\perp$.  Define 
$$\langle u,v\rangle = \langle u_1,v_1\rangle_V+\langle u_2,v_2\rangle_H$$

What happens here is that the space $H$ is treated as a direct sum of two Hilbert spaces. Changing the inner product on the finite-dimensional summand does not change anything essential.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning how that inner product on $V$ can be obtained: if $f \in V$, then $f = \sum_{j}\alpha_{j}\phi_{j}$ defines a map $L$ from $V$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ or $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ which maps $f$ to $(\alpha_{1},\cdots,\alpha_{n})$, and you can define $(f,g)_{V}=(Lf,Lg)_{\mathbb{C}^{n}}$.